# rpy2 @rpath issue on OS X 10.7

Tags: python, r, macos, anaconda, rpy2

I’m trying to use rpy2 to call into R from Python. This used to work for me a while back, but I’ve just re-installed Anaconda and upgraded to Python3.5 and R 3.1.3 (still on OS X 10.7). Now when I run:

```
from rpy2 import robjects as ro
```

I get the rpath error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/User1/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-35m-darwin.so, 2): 
Library not loaded: @rpath/R/lib/libR.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/User1/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-35m-darwin.so
Reason: image not found
```

This is from inside Eclipse (Kepler) with the python environment built using Anaconda/conda. The R installation was done using the standard CRAN install (picking the latest version that would install on OS X 10.7, which is the 3.1.3), which put it here:

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/lib/libR.dylib

Looking at:

```
otool -L _rinterface.cpython-35m-darwin.so
```

shows the path the rpy2 interface binary is looking for:

```
_rinterface.cpython-35m-darwin.so:

@rpath/R/lib/libR.dylib (compatibility version 3.2.0, current version 3.2.2)

/usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.5)

@rpath/./libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.8)

/usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 46.1.0)

/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)

/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)

/Users/aaronmeurer/anaconda/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

which shows the rpath call, which clearly doesn’t find the libR.dylib at the above installed location.

I’ve trawled other related posts and tried using install_name_tool to modify the @rpath/R/lib/libR.dylib to a fixed path to the libR.dylib, but no joy, I get an error message about _rinterface.cpython-35m-darwin.so being a malformed object:

```
install_name_tool -change @rpath/R/lib/libR.dylib /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/lib/libR.dylib _rinterface.cpython-35m-darwin.so
install_name_tool: object: _rinterface.cpython-35m-darwin.so malformed object (unknown load command 16)
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: How was rpy2 installed ? (`pip install rpy2` or through anaconda ?)

Comment: (note: the latest rpy2, 2.7.x series at the time of writing, is not tested with R < 3.2.x)

Comment: thanks for replying Laurent

Comment: conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/r rpy2

Comment: and pip install rpy2

Comment: Is there a recommended earlier rpy2 version to use with R 3.1?

Comment: rpy2-2.5.x would be OK with that version of R (http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.5/html/overview.html#requirements)... but Python 3.5 will almost certainly not work (rpy2-2.7.4 fixed a critical issue with Python 3.5). Why use Python 3.5 and drag an older R ? Just upgrade R.

Comment: Thanks Laurent. I've upgraded to El Capitan (OSX 10.11.2) and re-installed Anaconda and R fully, so now on R 3.2.2. I've tried the pip install rpy2 which gives me a 2.7.5 version, but still end up with the same rpath error (after setting the R_HOME env variable). I'm wondering whether a conda install would give a better result - given that I've built everything else (Python3.5, R3.2.2) inside Anaconda. On the conda site, there is only a rpy2 2.7.0, so out of the box the conda install just grabs that. Do you know how I can get conda install to pick up the 2.7.4 (or 2.7.5)?

Comment: I'd suggest the opposite (try without conda) because I have seen several reports of issues associated with conda in the past. However, I am not using conda myself so I am unable to tell to which extent this was caused by exotic configurations on the user side.

Comment: I don't have a system with OS X on which I could try out, but someone got it working, it seems: https://gist.github.com/nickgravish/7ab136fc3bcbbac8316b

Comment: I'm trying somethign similar do you have any insight? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42126077/use-rpy2-with-packages-installed-in-r-conda-environment