# Use `rpy2` with packages installed for `R` in conda virtual environment?

Tags: python, r, environment-variables, conda, rpy2

I have been trying to keep my environment non-redundant and clean so I made an `R` environment and wiped out all other existing `R`s on my computer.

That environment is called `r-conda` and it is in:

`/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/r-conda/bin/R`

I realized I didn't have `rpy2` installed and to install it through conda it wanted to install the a new version of `R` and all of the `r-essentials` which I don't want since I already have a perfectly working R environment.

I realized I could install `rpy2` for the `Python` associated within the `R conda` environment:

```
source activate r-conda
pip install rpy2
source deactivate
```

But not all of the paths are lined up

**How can I make `rpy2` recognize all of my `R` associated files and paths in my `r-conda` environment?**

It's not finding the files correctly when I am trying to import packges:

```
os.environ['R_HOME'] = "/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/r-conda/bin/R"
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
importr("dynamicTreeCut")

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-8b0a88dfe12d> in <module>()
      1 # os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/r-conda/bin/'
      2 os.environ['R_HOME'] = "/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/r-conda/bin/R"
----> 3 from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
      4 importr("dynamicTreeCut")

/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py in <module>()
     14 import itertools
     15 from datetime import datetime
---> 16 import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
     17 import rpy2.rlike.container as rlc
     18 

/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py in <module>()
     90 del(os)
     91 
---> 92 from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,
     93                                          emptyenv,
     94                                          endr,

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/jespinoz/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Fixed that error by adding this to my `~/.bash_profile` but generated a similar new error:
I gave this a try, and the error changed:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/r-conda/lib/R/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" 

>>> from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libicuuc.54.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/jespinoz/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

So I tried this, then got the same error:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/envs/r-conda/lib/R/lib/:/Users/jespinoz/anaconda/pkgs/icu-54.1-0/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

If I use `conda install rpy2` it wants to install a `Python=3.5.2` even though my default version of my main conda environment is `Python=3.6`. @asmeurer gave a suggestion to specify `Python=3.6` when installing `rpy2` in my `r-conda` environment but now it's looking like a package conflicting error:

```
(r-conda) jespinozlt-osx:~ jespinoz$ conda install rpy2 python=3.6
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python 3.6*
  - r-permute
  - rpy2
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package
```

Answer (score 4):

You should `conda install rpy2` instead of pip installing it. Also, keep the environment activated. You should conda install `python` and any Python packages you want to use into the same R environment, so that everything is done in a single environment.

Comment: When I `conda install rpy2` from with my `r-conda` environment, it wants to install another version of `python` even though the default `python` for that environment is my main version `python=3.6`.  Is my only option to either install 2 versions of R, 2 versions of Python, or merge them into the same environment?  I feel like there is something I can do with my paths and environment variables to tell `rpy2` where my `R` files are located.

Comment: I'm not sure why it does that, but you can force it to keep the python version you want by including it in the install command, like `conda install rpy2 python=3.6`.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that.  Nice, thanks!  Though, it looks like I'm getting some conflicting errors (updating the question b/c formatting)
`

Comment: I guess it means r-permute needs to be updated. You'll have to bug the Continuum folks to update it (I don't work there anymore).